# Beginning with an arbitrary classical equation for energy, how do I get the QM Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

For linear momentum I can use the de Broglie equation, but what about energy in terms of moment of inertia or some other form?

Comment: Do you mean quantization in [old quantum mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_quantum_theory)?

Comment: I guess so.  It relates to a homework problem of finding the Hamiltonian of a QM rigid rotor using the Hamiltonian of a classical rigid rotor.  I wasn't sure how to do that or generalize the process.

Comment: Rotator is also given in above link. If you have any specific doubts regarding it you can include them in your question.